# Editing a dictionary value edits the value for all keys

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having trouble modifying a dictionary key in a loop without modifying all of the keys at once.

I initiate my dictionary with dict.fromkeys and the output is what I expect.

```
times_genus_contaminated = dict.fromkeys(expected_genus,[0,{}])
{'Aedes': [0, {}], 'Homo': [0, {}], 'Mus': [0, {}]}
```

I then try to loop through my data, incrementing the 0 by 1 each time that key appears as the first item in my list for that loop. The issue I'm having is that the increment happens for all 3 keys and not the one being specified.

Sample Code

```
for sample in contaminated_samples:
    for contamination in sample['contamination']:
        genus = contamination[0]
        times_genus_contaminated[genus][0] += 1
print(times_genus_contaminated)
```

Sample Data (each line is an example of what would be printed if you printed `contamination` after the 2 for loops)

```
['Homo', 'Pan', '9597', 23022, 47.66]
['Homo', 'Gorilla', '9595', 1816, 3.76]
['Mus', 'Mastomys', '35658', 532, 1.11]
['Mus', 'Arvicanthis', '61156', 965, 2.03]
['Aedes', 'Mayaro', '59301', 277, 2.19]
```

Based on the sample data the end result should be:

```
{'Aedes': [1, {}], 'Homo': [2, {}], 'Mus': [2, {}]}
```

But the output I'm getting is:

```
{'Aedes': [5, {}], 'Homo': [5, {}], 'Mus': [5, {}]}
```

Solution:

```
for sample in contaminated_samples:
    for contamination in sample['contamination']:
        print(contamination)
        genus = contamination[0]
        temp = times_genus_contaminated[genus][:]
        temp[0] += 1
        times_genus_contaminated[genus] = temp
```

Comment: All of the dictionary values for the different dictionary keys point to the same list object, so modifications to this list object shows up in all of the values. Create a copy of the list object, modify the copy and assign the copy as the value for the given dictionary key instead of modification of the list object elements to avoid mirroring the changes in all of the values.

Comment: Much appreciated @Claudio, added solution to post

Comment: The more straightforward solution would be to create the dictionary the right way in a loop over the keys assigning a copy of the list object as value to each dictionary key in first place. This will avoid unnecessary copying of the list object in the processing loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with:

```
times_genus_contaminated = dict.fromkeys(expected_genus, [0,{}])
```

is that the default dictionary value `[0,{}]` for all the different dictionary keys is evaluated and created only once and not each time for each different key/value entry created in the dictionary while looping over items of `expected_genus`.

The consequence of the above is that all of the dictionary values for the different dictionary keys point to the same list object, so modifications to this list object elements show up in all the values and not only the one just modified.

This is the reason why all of the additions are done to the same list object element being the value for all the dictionary keys giving the final value of `[5, {}]` which is then shown as value for all the keys.

Python documentation on `dict.fromkeys(iterable[, value])` says:

> fromkeys() is a dict class method that returns a new dictionary. The value defaults to None. All of the values refer to just a single instance, so **it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object** such as an (empty) list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.

Replacing `[0,{}]` with for example a call to a `stdval()` function ( `def stdval(): return [0,{}]` ) returning `[0,{}]` won't help here as the function call will also be evaluated once before running the loop for creating the dictionary items with `dict.fromkeys()`.

Creating a copy of the list object, modifying the copy and assigning the copy as the value for the given dictionary key instead of modification of the list object elements helps to avoid mirroring the changes in all of the values, but ...

**The most straightforward solution is to create the dictionary with explicit different list objects as values for different keys in first place:**

```
expected_genus = ['Aedes','Homo','Mus']
times_genus_contaminated = dict()
for genus in expected_genus:
    times_genus_contaminated[genus] = [0, {}] # <- creates a new list for each genus
```

which can also be done using the dictionary comprehension:

```
times_genus_contaminated = { key:[0, {}] for key in expected_genus }
```

---

```
print(times_genus_contaminated) 
print('---')
contaminated_samples = [

 {'contamination': [['Homo', 'Pan', '9597', 23022, 47.66], 
                    ['Homo', 'Gorilla', '9595', 1816, 3.76],]}

,{'contamination': [['Mus', 'Mastomys', '35658', 532, 1.11],
                    ['Mus', 'Arvicanthis', '61156', 965, 2.03],]}

,{'contamination': [['Aedes', 'Mayaro', '59301', 277, 2.19],]}

,]

for sample in contaminated_samples:
    print(sample)
    for contamination in sample['contamination']:
        print(contamination)
        genus = contamination[0]
        times_genus_contaminated[genus][0] += 1

print('---')
print(times_genus_contaminated)
```

prints:

```
{'Aedes': [0, {}], 'Homo': [0, {}], 'Mus': [0, {}]}
---
{'contamination': [['Homo', 'Pan', '9597', 23022, 47.66], ['Homo', 'Gorilla', '9595', 1816, 3.76]]}
['Homo', 'Pan', '9597', 23022, 47.66]
['Homo', 'Gorilla', '9595', 1816, 3.76]
{'contamination': [['Mus', 'Mastomys', '35658', 532, 1.11], ['Mus', 'Arvicanthis', '61156', 965, 2.03]]}
['Mus', 'Mastomys', '35658', 532, 1.11]
['Mus', 'Arvicanthis', '61156', 965, 2.03]
{'contamination': [['Aedes', 'Mayaro', '59301', 277, 2.19]]}
['Aedes', 'Mayaro', '59301', 277, 2.19]
---
{'Aedes': [1, {}], 'Homo': [2, {}], 'Mus': [2, {}]}
```